# linq where list contains any in list

Tags: c#, linq

Using linq, how can I retrieve a list of items where its list of attributes match another list?

Take this simple example and pseudo code:

```
List<Genres> listofGenres = new List<Genre>() { "action", "comedy" });   
var movies = _db.Movies.Where(p => p.Genres.Any() in listofGenres);
```

Comment: Pseudo code makes this question too vague to answer. For one, it's not clear how equality of `Genre` is defined.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
var movies = _db.Movies.Where(p => p.Genres.Intersect(listOfGenres).Any());
```

Comment: i was trying to use this query for search box, it searches any character in Person_Name column,  i got this error :'DbIntersectExpression requires arguments with compatible collection ResultTypes' so i tried `.StartWith, .EndsWith, .Contains` from [here](http://blogs.telerik.com/openaccessteam/posts/12-04-17/string-matching-in-linq.aspx) it works, but what can be done to use your query

Comment: @stom: We don't have nearly enough information to help you with that - you should ask a new question with a *lot* more context.

Comment: @JonSkeet I always use Contains method for these kind of queries. I was curious by seeing your answer and checked the internal implementation and found that Intersect uses Set. Can you tell me the performance difference between those two methods?

Comment: @Rebornx: Using `Contains` repeatedly ends up as an O(x*y) operation in time, but O(1) in space, where x is the size of the first collection and y is the size of the second. Using `Intersect` is O(x+y) in time but O(y) in space - it constructs a hashset from the second collection, which makes it quick to check for inclusion for any item from the first collection. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-16-intersect-and-build-fiddling/ for details

Comment: @JonSkeet Is there any significant performance implications when choosing to "chain" `.Where()` with `.Any()`? Since `.Any()` has an overload that takes a predicate, is it better to just use that overload instead of chaining?

Comment: @SteveBoniface: Note that this isn't calling `.Where(...).Any()` - it's calling `.Where(x => x...Any())`. The Any is *within* the predicate.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, that's important to note. Generally, would there ever be a reason to do something like: `myCollection.Where(x => <<some predicate>>).Any()` when one can just do `myCollection.Any(x => <<some predicate>>)` ? Are there major performance differences between the two?

Comment: @SteveBoniface: I wouldn't expect so, no. I'd expect the latter to be very slightly faster, as there's less indirection.

Answer (score 74):

You can use a `Contains` query for this:

```
var movies = _db.Movies.Where(p => p.Genres.Any(x => listOfGenres.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use `HashSet` instead of `List` for `listofGenres` you can do:

```
var genres = new HashSet<Genre>() { "action", "comedy" };   
var movies = _db.Movies.Where(p => genres.Overlaps(p.Genres));
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is also possible like this?

```
var movies = _db.Movies.TakeWhile(p => p.Genres.Any(x => listOfGenres.Contains(x));
```

Is "TakeWhile" worse than "Where" in sense of performance or clarity?

Comment: `TakeWhile` is a different function - it will stop iterating when it does not find a match.

Answer (score 2):

Or like this

```
class Movie
{
  public string FilmName { get; set; }
  public string Genre { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var listofGenres = new List<string> { "action", "comedy" };

var Movies = new List<Movie> {new Movie {Genre="action", FilmName="Film1"},
                new Movie {Genre="comedy", FilmName="Film2"},
                new Movie {Genre="comedy", FilmName="Film3"},
                new Movie {Genre="tragedy", FilmName="Film4"}};

var movies = Movies.Join(listofGenres, x => x.Genre, y => y, (x, y) => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `Genre` is an Entity and has its own Properties such as `Title`, use the following code:

```
var listofGenresName = new List<string> { "action", "comedy" };
var movies = _db.Movies.Where(p => p.Genres.Any(x => listofGenresName.Any(g=> g == x.Title)));
```