# Display news based on multiple tags from multiple rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am developing news site in asp.net 4.0 with c#, Entity Framework 5 & SQLServer 2008

after reading news I show related news based on matched tags from other news

```
var article = (from c in ctx.Articles where c.ArticleID == "10" select c).SingleOrDefault();
var tags = new List<string>();
string[] words = article.Tags.Split(',');
foreach (string word in words)
{
     if (word != "") { tags.Add(word.Trim()); }
}
```

current news has following tags :
sun, moon, star

```
var relatedNews = (from c in ctx.Articles where tags.Contains(c.Tags) select c).Take(10);
```

if other news has single tag "e.g. sun" it works fine
but if it has "sun, galaxy" or multiple tags it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but I think the problem is:

```
where tags.Contains(c.Tags)
```

Now the articles must have all the supplied tags (sun AND galaxy), instead of one or more of the tags (sun OR galaxy). Is that really what you want or am I misunderstanding your question/code? Shouldn't it be something like:

```
where c.Any(x => tags.Contains(x))
```

Something like this should select items which have either one of the tags, or both. See also:

[linq where list contains any in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667675/linq-where-list-contains-any-in-list)