# List of object - combining condition check within the list with local variables outside of it

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Continuation of previous question
[linq where list contains any in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667675/linq-where-list-contains-any-in-list)

I have a list of objectA
Where ObjectA has 2 properties - string action,bool valid

```
Ex action =abc, valid = true
action xyz , valid = false
```

etc

I have two local variables

```
string actiontocheck ="abc"

string validitychecker ="somevalidvalue" // it can be something else too
```

I want to check something like
Iterate through list 
.

```
if any of the action in the list contains actiontocheck and 
the corresponding valid flag is true, 

if(validitychecker == "somevalidvalue")
  set flag to false
```

What I have tried

```
 if (List1.Any(a => (a.Action.Contains(actiontocheck)) && a.valid)
        {
            if (validitychecker == "somevalidvalue")
            {
                Ignore = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried? A quick google should point you to `Any` or `Select` (your req is slightly vague)

Comment: added code what i hve tried - the 1st if didnt look feasible with any,

Comment: Still not following what the point is, but it looks fine to me

Comment: the if condition gives an error - Cannot apply && to operands of type bool and system.nullable<bool>

Comment: try to replace `&& a.valid` with `&& a.HasValue && a.valid.Value`

Comment: or you could do `a.valid == true` which will cause the same unboxing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the type of `a.valid`. There are many ways to solve this issue, but if you know that it will have a value of `True` or `False` every time, you should be able to simply write:

```
if (List1.Any(a => (a.Action.Contains(actiontocheck)) && a.valid.Value)
{
    if (validitychecker == "somevalidvalue")
    {
        Ignore = true;
    }
}
```