# Linq Where list Contains item in another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given the following Structure

```
public class WorkOrderItem 
{
    [Key] 
    public long WorkOrderItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }      
}

public class Job 
{
    [Key]
    public long JobId { get; set; }
    public long? WorkOrderItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public virtual Element ResultElement { get; set; }
}
```

How would i get a list of Items where the item had a job that the ResultElementid was in a `List<long>()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667675/linq-where-list-contains-any-in-list.

Comment: You have forgotten to add the class `Element`, i assume it has an `Id` property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Any` + `Contains`:

```
var query = workOrderItems
    .Where(item => item.Jobs.Any(j => longList.Contains(j.ResultElement.Id)));
```

( presuming that the class `Element` has an `Id` property since you've stated *ResultElementid* )

Comment: I always forget some vital Linq method, in this case it was ANy(). Cheers.