# How do you check if a string contains any strings from a list in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to search a database to see if a string contains elements of a list of search terms.

```
var searchTerms = new List<string> { "car", "232" };
var result = context.Data.Where(data => data.Name.Contains(searchTerms) ||
                                        data.Code.Contains(searchTerms));
```

This would work if searchTerms was a string but I've been trying to get it to work with a list of strings.

Essentially I need SQL which would say

```
SELECT * FROM Data
WHERE Name LIKE '%car%'
OR Name LIKE '%232%'
OR Code LIKE '%car%'
OR Code LIKE '%232%'
```

[linq where list contains any in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667675/linq-where-list-contains-any-in-list) seems to be the closes thing I could find to the situation.

`Where(data => searchTerms.Contains(data.Name) || searchTerms.Contains(data.Code)` only brings back exact matches to the search terms list.

I have tried searching for multiple keyword search in Entity Framework also and have exhausted that effort. Is there any way to achieve what I am aiming for?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try using `Any` method, I'm not sure whether it's supported but it's worth trying:

```
var result = context.Data.Where(data => searchTerms.Any(x => data.Name.Contains(x)) ||
                                        searchTerms.Any(x => data.Code.Contains(x));
```

If this gives you `NotSupportedException` you can add `AsEnumerable` before `Where` to fetch all records and execute the query in memory rather than DB.

Comment: What if Data has 1 million records?

Comment: @hunter If DB has too many records and this solution impacts performance then create a DB Function and let the database does what the database does ;-). The above worked fine for me with < 5000 records

Answer (score 20):

I'm late to the party but using the [SearchExtensions nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions/) you could do something like the following

```
var result = context.Data.Search(x => x.Name, x => x.Code).Containing(searchTerms);
```

This builds an expression tree so will still perform the query on the server (and not in memory) and will essentially run the SQL you desire above

Comment: Better than using Any which can generate too deeply nested query and lead to exception.

Comment: @NinjaNye does this work against EF Core 5?

Answer (score 3):

Following is a fully functional example, of how to implement different kind of searches, using multiple keywords.

This example was especially directed at @Hamza Khanzada 's [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60914868/linq-to-entities-string-contains-a-list)  regarding `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`.

It does something similar to the library @NinjaNye named.

---

The **simplest approach** is used by `EqualsQuery()`, which just tests the database field against an exact match of a keyword (though casing doesn't matter). This is what @Mohsen Esmailpour suggested.

It generates SQL similar to the following:

```sql
SELECT `i`.`IceCreamId`, `i`.`Name`
FROM `IceCreams` AS `i`
WHERE LOWER(`i`.`Name`) IN ('cookie', 'berry')
ORDER BY `i`.`IceCreamId`
```

However, this is probably not sufficient for your case, because you are not looking for *exact* matches, but want to return rows with fields that just *contain* the keyword (and possibly other words as well).

---

A **second approach** is used by `AndContainsQuery()`, which is still very simple, but does something slightly different. It returns only results, that contain *all* the keyword (and possibly orther words as well).

It generates SQL similar to the following:

```sql
set @__keyword_0 = 'Cookie';
set @__keyword_1 = 'choco';

SELECT `i`.`IceCreamId`, `i`.`Name`
FROM `IceCreams` AS `i`
WHERE
    (LOCATE(LCASE(@__keyword_0), LCASE(`i`.`Name`)) > 0) AND
    (LOCATE(LCASE(@__keyword_1), LCASE(`i`.`Name`)) > 0)
ORDER BY `i`.`IceCreamId`;
```

This is not what you want, but I though it would be nice to show as well, because it is very simple and can be done without manually building expression trees.

---

Finally, the **third approach** is used by `orContainsQuery()`, and builds part of the expression tree manually. It constructs the body of the `WHERE` expression of multiple nested `OR` expressions.
This *is* what you want.

It generates SQL similar to the following:

```sql
set @__keyword_0 = 'berry';
set @__keyword_1 = 'Cookie';

SELECT `i`.`IceCreamId`, `i`.`Name`
FROM `IceCreams` AS `i`
WHERE
    (LOCATE(LCASE(@__keyword_0), LCASE(`i`.`Name`)) > 0) OR
    (LOCATE(LCASE(@__keyword_1), LCASE(`i`.`Name`)) > 0)
ORDER BY `i`.`IceCreamId`;
```

---

Here is the fully functional console project:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseMySql(
                    "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=so60914868",
                    b => b.ServerVersion(new ServerVersion("8.0.20-mysql")))
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCream>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasData(
                        new IceCream {IceCreamId = 1, Name = "Vanilla"},
                        new IceCream {IceCreamId = 2, Name = "Berry"},
                        new IceCream {IceCreamId = 3, Name = "Strawberry"},
                        new IceCream {IceCreamId = 4, Name = "Berry & Fruit"},
                        new IceCream {IceCreamId = 5, Name = "cookie"},
                        new IceCream {IceCreamId = 6, Name = "Chocolate chip cookie"},
                        new IceCream {IceCreamId = 7, Name = "Choco-Cookie & Dough"});
                });
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }

            EqualsQuery();
            AndContainsQuery();
            OrContainsQuery();
        }

        private static void EqualsQuery()
        {
            //
            // This will find only matches that match the word exactly (though case-insensitive):
            //

            using var context = new Context();
            
            var keywords = new[] {"Cookie", "berry"}
                .Select(s => s.ToLower())
                .ToArray();

            var equalsResult = context.IceCreams
                .Where(i => keywords.Contains(i.Name.ToLower()))
                .OrderBy(i => i.IceCreamId)
                .ToList();

            Debug.Assert(equalsResult.Count == 2);
            Debug.Assert(
                equalsResult[0]
                    .Name == "Berry");
            Debug.Assert(
                equalsResult[1]
                    .Name == "cookie");
        }

        private static void AndContainsQuery()
        {
            //
            // This will find matches, that contain ALL keywords (and other words, case-insensitive):
            //

            using var context = new Context();
            
            var keywords = new[] {"Cookie", "choco"};

            var andContainsQuery = context.IceCreams.AsQueryable();

            foreach (var keyword in keywords)
            {
                andContainsQuery = andContainsQuery.Where(i => i.Name.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            }

            var andContainsResult = andContainsQuery
                .OrderBy(i => i.IceCreamId)
                .ToList();

            Debug.Assert(andContainsResult.Count == 2);
            Debug.Assert(
                andContainsResult[0]
                    .Name == "Chocolate chip cookie");
            Debug.Assert(
                andContainsResult[1]
                    .Name == "Choco-Cookie & Dough");
        }

        private static void OrContainsQuery()
        {
            //
            // This will find matches, that contains at least one keyword (and other words, case-insensitive):
            //

            using var context = new Context();
            
            var keywords = new[] {"Cookie", "berry"};

            // The lambda parameter.
            var iceCreamParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IceCream), "i");

            // Build the individual conditions to check against.
            var orConditions = keywords
                .Select(keyword => (Expression<Func<IceCream, bool>>) (i => i.Name.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                .Select(lambda => (Expression) Expression.Invoke(lambda, iceCreamParameter))
                .ToList();

            // Combine the individual conditions to an expression tree of nested ORs.
            var orExpressionTree = orConditions
                .Skip(1)
                .Aggregate(
                    orConditions.First(),
                    (current, expression) => Expression.OrElse(expression, current));
            
            // Build the final predicate (a lambda expression), so we can use it inside of `.Where()`.
            var predicateExpression = (Expression<Func<IceCream, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(
                orExpressionTree,
                iceCreamParameter);

            // Compose and execute the query.
            var orContainsResult = context.IceCreams
                .Where(predicateExpression)
                .OrderBy(i => i.IceCreamId)
                .ToList();

            Debug.Assert(orContainsResult.Count == 6);
            Debug.Assert(orContainsResult[0].Name == "Berry");
            Debug.Assert(orContainsResult[1].Name == "Strawberry");
            Debug.Assert(orContainsResult[2].Name == "Berry & Fruit");
            Debug.Assert(orContainsResult[3].Name == "cookie");
            Debug.Assert(orContainsResult[4].Name == "Chocolate chip cookie");
            Debug.Assert(orContainsResult[5].Name == "Choco-Cookie & Dough");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! In ef core 5 instead of  i.Name.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) you have to use i.Name.Contains(keyword) in order to get IQuearyable otherwise it will be client evaluation. MS docs https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038

Answer (score 2):

This request will be executed on the database side

```
var searchTerms = new List<string> { "car", "232" };
Expressions<Func<Data, bool>> expression = it => false;
foreach(var searchTerm in searchTerms)
{
    expression = expression.Or(it => it.Name.Contains(searchTerm));
    //you can implement your own 'Or' extensions method, 
    //or use third-party libraries, i.e. LinqKit
}
var result = context.Data.Where(expression);
```

you can also use the Specification pattern, for code purity