# Is there a way to have multiple likes generated dynamically from an array of string values in EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I've set up a search textbox where the search will grab every word individually and search through a field using Contains.

Is there a way to search an array of string through Contains?

```
//Keep in mind that the array would be generated dynamically through textbox
string[] searchWords = { "hello", "world", "today" };

var articles = _swmDbContext.Articles
                        .Include(c => c.Category)
                        .Where(a => a.Title.Contains(searchWords));
```

searchWords obiviously does not work but trying to show what I want to achieve. searchWords[0] works because it is just one word.

I also tried below as suggested in other links but now the WHERE clause does not show up in query when i run debugger or profiler:

```
`var articles = _swmDbContext.Articles
                 .Include(c => c.Category)
                 .Where(a => searchWords.Any(w => a.Title.Contains(w)));
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ: Entity string field contains any of an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757214/linq-entity-string-field-contains-any-of-an-array-of-strings)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. This question is specific to EF Core, not just LINQ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like Entity Framework Core does not translate `.Any` and `.All` with `.Contains` in the above query to SQL statements. Instead it loads all otherwise matching data and does the search in memory.

If you want to find Articles which contain **all** search words in the Title you could dynamically add `.Where` conditions (I had a test database with Persons and a Comment field):

```
var query = (IQueryable<Person>)dbContext.Persons
    .Include(p => p.TaxIdentificationNumber);

foreach (var searchWord in searchWords)
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.Comment.Contains(searchWord));
}

var persons = query.ToList();
```

But if you want to find articles which contain **any** of the search words then you would need an `OR` in the `.Where` clause.

Written manually it would look like this:

```
.Where(p => p.Comment.Contains(searchWords[0]) || p.Comment.Contains(searchWords[1]))
```

But you can build the expression dynamically:

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> e1 = p => p.Comment.Contains(searchWords[0]);
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> e2 = p => p.Comment.Contains(searchWords[1]);
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> e3 = p => p.Comment.Contains(searchWords[2]);
var orExpression1 = Expression.OrElse(e1.Body, Expression.Invoke(e2, e1.Parameters[0]));
var orExpression2 = Expression.OrElse(orExpression1, Expression.Invoke(e3, e1.Parameters[0]));
var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(orExpression2, e1.Parameters);
```

and use it like this:

```
var persons = dbContext.Persons.Where(finalExpression).ToList();
```

as a function:

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> BuildOrSearchExpression(string[] searchWords)
{
    // searchWords must not be null or empty

    var expressions = searchWords.Select(s => (Expression<Func<Person, bool>>)(p => p.Comment.Contains(s))).ToList();

    if (expressions.Count == 1) return expressions[0];

    var orExpression = expressions.Skip(2).Aggregate(
        Expression.OrElse(expressions[0].Body, Expression.Invoke(expressions[1], expressions[0].Parameters[0])),
        (x, y) => Expression.OrElse(x, Expression.Invoke(y, expressions[0].Parameters[0])));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(orExpression, expressions[0].Parameters);
}
```

and use it

```
var persons = dbContext.Persons
    .Include(p => p.TaxIdentificationNumber)
    .Where(BuildOrSearchExpression(searchWords))
    .ToList();
```

If you exchange the `.OrElse` with `.AndAlso` all search words must be found like with multiple `.where` clauses.

When I did some research I also stumbled upon the PredicatedBuilder http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx and this SearchExtension https://stackoverflow.com/a/31682364/5550687. But I have not tried them and I don't know if they work with EF Core.

Comment: Expression function did the trick. This just let me like EF Core so much more. I think this is something they should build in for future releases. If I could, I would buy you a beer....cheers!

Comment: How would one add an OR statement to related data in that function e.g. they want to compare a property in TaxIdentificationNumber as well? @noox

Comment: Thanks for the virtual beer ;) I've not tried it, but maybe add another Expression with `Expression<Func<Person, bool>> e4 = p => p.TaxIdentificationNumber.Number.Contains(searchWord);`

Comment: This answered a lot of questions I've been struggling to understand with predicate building. Thank you!