# EF Core dynamic OR query from array

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an API and would like to query based on an array, but the number of parameters could be 1 or 1000.

Query URL:

```
https://localhost:1000/api/?uid=1a3d426d-2d37-43fd-b781-a7230235ba0f&names=John;Manuel;George;
```

What I am doing is splitting the string names in to an array and trying to use the array to query the table

```
string[] namesarray = names..Split(';');
```

What I want to do is return all employees on the company which contain each of the names using EF Core.

Comment: `context.Companies.Where(c => namesarray.Contains(c.Name))` if you want an exact match on name

Comment: It's not clear where you need help doing this. You only tell what you want, not where you experience a problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you want an exact match on name, then this will do it:

```
var companies = context.Companies
    .Where(c => namesarray.Contains(c.Name))
    .ToList();
```

This will generate SQL that looks *something* like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name...
FROM Companies
WHERE Name IN ('John', 'Manuel', 'George')
```

Alternatively of you want a partial match then you will need to build your expression manually since a query in the form of `.Any(... .Contains )` isn't supported in EF Core yet. If will however work in EF6, but this isn't of use to you. To do that, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56571232/1663001). For example:

```
private Expression<Func<Accounts, bool>> BuildOrSearchExpression(string[] searchWords)
{
    var expressions = searchWords
        .Select(s => (Expression<Func<Accounts, bool>>)(p => p.Name.Contains(s)))
        .ToList();

    if (expressions.Count == 1) return expressions[0];

    var orExpression = expressions.Skip(2).Aggregate(
        Expression.OrElse(expressions[0].Body, Expression.Invoke(expressions[1], expressions[0].Parameters[0])),
        (x, y) => Expression.OrElse(x, Expression.Invoke(y, expressions[0].Parameters[0])));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Accounts, bool>>(orExpression, expressions[0].Parameters);
}
```

And use like this:

```
var companies = context.Companies
    .Where(BuildOrSearchExpression(namesarray))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried `partial match`? As I know it is not supported with local collections.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Bah, it doesn't work in EF Core, only EF6. Good spot.