# Linq To Entities: String.Contains a list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am using `ASP.net Core 3.0` with `Entity Framework Core 3.0` and `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore` provider for `MySQL`, I need to query all the users that are from specific Towns.
Lets say for example I have a list of strings called `targettedTowns` in which I have the following towns

```
var targettedTowns = new List<string>() {"korangi","landhi","zia colony","shah faisal","quaidabad"};
```

- korangi
- landhi
- zia colony
- shah faisal
- quaidabad

Now I want to find all the users that are located in the `targettedTowns` list using Linq Lambda syntax.

Users in my database have their towns saved like

- Korangi
- Korangi-Zia Colony
- Korangi-Bhittai Colony
- Korangi-Allah Wala Town
- Landhi-Sherpao
- Landhi-Awami Colony
- Landhi-Sherabad
- ShahFaisal

What I am trying currently is

```
var users = context.Users.Where(x => x.Town.ToLower().Contains(targettedList)).ToList();
```

but as String.Contains does not take a list in argument so I cant use this.

Comment: I posted a complete answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61012195/2618319

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace `x.Town.ToLower()` with `targettedList` in where condition:

```
var users = context.Users.Where(x => targettedList.Contains(x.Town)).ToList();
```

Comment: That only brings the exact matches and users with Town `korangi-Bhittai Colony` would not be found using this

Comment: Ccould you please post the translated `tsql` of above linq query.