# Entity Framework Core - select records from table only where column in table matches all strings in list

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

So with Entity Framework Core, I have set up a view in the database that concatenates an address into one column, with the unique ID of the address as well, so effectively the view contains:

- `Id` (unique identifier of the address)
- `FullAddress` (concatenated column of the separate address columns, to allow it to be searched)

This part is working fine, and I can do a SQL query against it like this to find all addresses in the view:

```sql
select distinct 
    V.Id
from
    dbo.View_AddressFull V 
where 
    V.FullAddress like '%64%' and V.FullAddress like '%townName%'
```

The problem I'm having is trying to replicate this query in LINQ, especially considering how there could be more than 2 search terms, since it's an "Address" search box, the user can type in any address they would like to try like "15 MadeUpStreet TownName Country" - if I was to do this in raw SQL this would just mean more `and V.FullAddress like` selectors, or someway of doing it from a list.

So this is the linq I've written to try and do this ([idea adapted from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295702/how-do-you-check-if-a-string-contains-any-strings-from-a-list-in-entity-framewor)):

```csharp
string[] splitAddress = query.Address.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var matchingAddresses = await _dbContext.View_AddressFull
    .Where(data => splitAddress.All(x => data.FullAddress.Contains(x)))
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .Distinct()
    .ToListAsync();
```

My hope with this is that it would do something similar to the SQL query above, unfortunately Entity Framework Core isn't able to translate the query and I get this error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet.Where(a => splitAddress.All(x => a.FullAddress.Contains(x)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."

I did try switching to client evaluation as it suggests, by using an `AsEnumerable()`, but this didn't return any results, which leads me to believe I have done the where selector wrong which is also leading to the expression not being translateable in the first place?

My other idea, is to just give up trying to make this a linq query and execute this as RAW SQL via Entity Framework Core, and then do a further select to get only the distinct Id's from there... the only issue is, I can't think of how to do that without just concatenating more `and V.FullAddress like` onto the SQL search string for each search word that is entered - which potentially exposes me to SQL Injection?

Comment: The SQL query isn't really working. It can't use any indexes and has to scan the entire table each time. This can't scale to even moderate amounts of data. You should use SQL Server's [full text search indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15) and functions like FREETEXT instead of `LIKE '%whatever%'`

Comment: Doesn't scale means every search will have to read *and lock* every single row in the table each time, preventing other connections from making any modifications until the search finishes. Full scans will have to wait until any other connections have finished updating and released their Exclusive locks on the rows. This will cause delays for every connection that tries to use the same table

Comment: [FreeText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.freetext?view=efcore-3.1) is available as an EF Core Functions, so using it is easier than trying to generate the `LIKE` operators

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah, that does seem like it will be quite an issue - having quickly read into full text indexes it seems like it'll be a good idea to do, although I get an error `Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view because it is not full-text indexed.` when trying to do this on LocalDB (I guess localDB just doesn't support full text index?)

Comment: You have to add a full-text-search index the same way you add any other index

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As much as I would like a full text index to work, it simply won't - I kept running into issues; the view was not schema bound (fixed), no full text catalog existed (fixed), no unique index exists on the view (not possible to fix, duplicate composite keys exist) so full text index cannot be created without these 3 things in place, which leaves me stuck. Cannot create an index on a view that is using `distinct` either, which would have worked as that would have ensured no duplicates exist.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos here is a screenshot of the estimated execution plan, it seems that it is using indexes? https://i.imgur.com/wACPrPs.png

Comment: You need to index the *table fields*, not the view. just like any other index.