Access Property in Expression<Func<Object, bool>> of Object
I would like to find out, if a string (stored in Column OSchlagwoerter in the database) contains any string within a list of strings (stored in variable tags).
In order to achieve this, I want to loop through the list of tags and check for each tag if OSchlagwoerter contains it. However, I cannot access the field OSchlagwoerter of the object passed.
The database query looks like this
return dbctx.Images                 
    .Where(tagFilter(tags))
    .Select(x => new ImageObj()                
    .ToList();

The tagFilter Expression should look like this:
private Expression<Func<ImageObj, bool>> tagFilter(List<string> tags)
{
    if ( tags.Count > 0)
    {
        //This line does not work
        var tagsInDb = x => x.OSchlagwoerter;

        foreach (var t in tags)
        {
            if (tagsInDb .Contains(t))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

        //first approach, does not work, only finds one tag in columns with on word in it
        //return x => tags.Contains(x.OSchlagwoerter);
    }
    else
    {
        return x => true;
    }
}

Edit:
dbctx.Images is a table in the database of type ImageObj
OSchlagwoerter is defined as follows:
public class ImageObj {

   public string OSchlagwoerter { get; set; }

}


I don't have EF Core immediately available to test, but I believe you should be able to replace all the code in the if (tags.Count > 0) block with return x => tags.Any(t => x.OSchlagwoerter.Contains(t));. Does that work with your EF Core version?

You may be complicating the solution too much (or I may not be understanding correctly what you want). But if all you need is to check whether the value in database column exists in the list - here is a simple solution:
List<string> tags = ...;
return dbctx.Images                 
    .Where(x => tags.Any(t => t == x.OSchlagwoerter))
    .Select(x => new ImageObj())
    .ToList();

If I understand correctly, it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/27295828/184509

You are right, this is a duplicate. Thank you!

However, your solution is not correct. Instead of t == x.OSchlagwoerter I need t => x.OSchlagwoerter.Contains(t) which throws a ValueBufferExpression Exception

@Mister832 - your question seems very similar to What is the syntax for a LINQ filter for List?.  The answer ther by Eugene Podskal is basically the same as this one here.  If it's not working, might you please edit to share your framework version and the traceback you get when you try this solution here?  Thanks!
