# How Query for contain any list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Class Group and a List

I include  [dotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0sowaG)

```
class Group
{
    public List<int> manyID;
    public int otherID;
}

    List<Group> allGroup = new List<Group>();
    Group g;

    g = new Group();
    g.manyID = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 3 } );
    g.otherID = 1;
    allGroup.Add(g);

    g = new Group();
    g.manyID = new List<int>(new int[] { 0, 2, 4 } );
    g.otherID = 2;
    allGroup.Add(g);

    g = new Group();
    g.manyID = new List<int>(new int[] { 2, 3 } );
    g.otherID = 3;
    allGroup.Add(g);
```

I want filter all the Groups with any ID from manyID appearing in subGroup list.

```
Group subGroup = new Group();
subGroup.manyID = new List<int>(new int[] { 0, 1 } );
```

For a single ID i know how do it. This will bring only first group.

```
List<Group> filterGroup = allGroup
              .Where( a => subGroup.manyID.Contains( a.otherID))
              .ToList();
```

What for the list? This should bring first 2 groups.

```
List<Group> filterGroup = allGroup
              .Where( a => subGroup.manyID.Contains( **a.manyID**))
              .ToList();
```

Comment: What you need is the intersect method,check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667675/linq-where-list-contains-any-in-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    filterGroup = allGroup
         .Where(a => subGroup.manyID.Intersect(a.manyID).Any())
         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
var filterGroup = allGroup
         .Where(a => a.manyID.Any(subGroup.manyID.Contains))
         .ToList();
```