# 2sxc Linq query for Categories

Tags: c#, linq, 2sxc

I have entities: Documents, Category, DocList

Documents and DocumentList can have multiple categories selected.

I want to make filter for Documents that are in one or more categories.

```
// all documents
var items = AsDynamic(App.Query["DocList"]["AllDocs"]);
// categories for filter
var fcat = Content.Category;

//linq query??
items = items.Where(d=>d.Category ....????....);
```

Can and how I can make this kind of filter?

Content.Category is list of Categories.

So I want to show list of items if there are in any of categories, not only one

something like this: [linq where list contains any in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667675/linq-where-list-contains-any-in-list)

Comment: What is the type of `fcat`? is it a collection?

Comment: Category  is  DynamicEntity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on: dnn **9.1.1** / 2sxc **9.14.0**

My final code:

```
@using System
@using ToSic.SexyContent
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using System.Linq
@{
    var items = AsDynamic(App.Data["Document"]);
    var tags = Content.Tags;
    items = items.Where(i => (i.Tags as List<DynamicEntity>).Any(c => ((List<DynamicEntity>)tags).Any(f => c.EntityId == f.EntityId)));
}
<div class="sc-element">
    <h1>@Content.Title</h1>
    @Edit.Toolbar(Content)
</div>
@foreach(var t in items)
{
    <div>@t.Title</div>
}
```

Document has field : Title (string) and Tags (Tag Entity / multiple)

Content is "Document List" with field "Tags" (type of Tag / multiple)

That way my code work.

Comment: Perfect. BTW: You probably just need the first `as List<...>`, the second one `c => ((List...)` is probably not necessary

Answer (score 1):

So parts of this are explained in the wiki https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/DotNet-Query-Linq

but I must admit that there is no example for exactly your question. I believe you want something like:

```
// filter - keep only those that have this Category
// note that the compare must run on the EntityId because of object wrapping/unwrapping
    items = items.Where(i => 
        (i.Category as List<dynamic>).Any(c => c.EntityId == fcat.EntityId))
```

So this should work :)

Additional solution if fcat is a list should be approx. like this

```
// filter - keep only those that have this Category
// note that the compare must run on the EntityId because of object wrapping/unwrapping
    items = items.Where(i => 
        (i.Category as List<dynamic>).Any(c => fcat.Any(f => c.EntityId == f.EntityId)))
```

If this causes an error, you'll probably need to cast fcat into something like

```
((List<dynamic>)fcat).Any(...)
```

Comment: I make mistake before and This don't work, becouse fcat = list of dynamic entities.

Comment: I need something like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667675/linq-where-list-contains-any-in-list

Comment: I made a correction which should cover your case - did it help?

Comment: sorry for late response. I try your update with variations but stuck with message: 
Error: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ToSic.SexyContent.DynamicEntity>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>

Comment: Did you use List<dynamic> or List<object>? You should really use List<dynamic>

Comment: BTW: if that is the whole problem, just replace List<dynamic> with List<ToSic.SexyContent.DynamicEn‌​tity>

Comment: I change code like you said and now is OK, I also posted answer with new full code..