# LINQ - Removing items in a List<T> that contain one item of an Array in any order or position

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write something similar to the following with LINQ:

```
var media = from s in db.Media select s;       
string[] criteria = {"zombies", "horror"};

mediaList.RemoveAll(media.Where(s => s.description.Inersect(criteria).Any())); 

//mediaList is a List(T) containing instances of the Media model.
```

I thought [linq where list contains any in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667675/linq-where-list-contains-any-in-list)'s solution would apply in this case but my compiler complains that "*string does not contain a definition for Intersect*".

The behaviour I am expecting is for *Media* items that contain the words **zombies** or **horror** but not both in their description to be taken out of the list i.e.

- A **horror** movie.
- A movie with a lot of **zombies**.

But items like the following should stay in the list:

- A **horror** movie with **zombies**.
- The best **zombies** and the best **horror**.

The Media class:

```
public class Media
{
    public int mediaID { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

The *description* field contains very long paragraphs. I am afraid the solution is very obvious but for the life of me I cannot work it out.

**EDIT:** added a better explanation of the behaviour expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusing some methods here.

[`List<T>.RemoveAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall) takes a `Predicate<T>` as parameter and removes all elements from the list for which this prediate returns `true`. So what you want could be somehting like that:

```
mediaList.RemoveAll(m => criteria.Any(crit => m.description.Contains(crit));
```

But note that this will also remove `"A movie about nonzombies"`.

---

UPDATE after your clarification:

```
mediaList.RemoveAll(m => 
    {
        int count = criteria.Count(crit => m.description.Contains(crit));
        return count > 0 && count < criteria.Length;
    });
```

This removes all entries that contain at least one word of `criteria`, but not all of them. (it still does not match *"whole words only"*, though).

Comment: Apologies but I made some pretty critical mistakes in my question. Particularly on the "behaviour expected" part.

Comment: @DanL updated my answer. Please try not to post moving targets.

Comment: I've been playing around with that code but it always fails at media.Description. The IntelliSense does not show any of the Media properties after I type media and instead shows "string does not contain a definition for description".

Comment: @DanL I fixed the spelling (`description` is lower case in your code). But the error you describe is strange. In my second code sample, _if_ `mediaList` really is a `List<Media>`, then `media` is of type `Media`, not `string`. Please verify that you copied the code correctly.

Comment: @DanL Note that `Intersect` as in your code can't work as `description` is a `string`, not an array of "words".

Comment: made a little mistake while copying although the error is still the same.`mediaList` is of type `List<media>` but seems like the `media.description` is using `media` instead - which was declared on the first line of my code and is a `IQueryable<media>`.

Comment: Also note that the local cannot me called `media` as it throws _cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter_. (I used it on `var media = from s in db.Media select s;  `) Easily fixed by just naming it something else.

Comment: @DanL you're right, `media` was already used. I renamed it to `m` in my answer. Did that solve the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid it still throws a _IQueryable<Media> does not contain a definition for 'description'_

Comment: Then you still use the `media` variable name, be sure to replace it inside the `RemoveAll(....)` method call/lambda.

Comment: You are correct, although when running the code `crit` throws a _NullPointerException_  inside the `.Contains()`. Sorry to keep bugging you.

Comment: So you probably have rows in your db where `description` is `NULL`. you can fix that for example via `m.description?.Contains(crit) ?? false`... but that's another (basic c#) question. I leave my office now, so this will be my last comment on that. Hope my answer could help so far.

Comment: Incredibly helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @RenéVogt: what's the `&& count < criteria.Length` about? It makes sure you never match 3 out of 2 criteria. The `m => criteria.Any(crit => m.description.Contains(crit)` predicate was sufficient.

Comment: @tinudu no, it makes sure you don't match 2 out of 2 criteria, which was Op's later requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
  var reuslt = mediaList.RemoveAll(media => criteria.Any(c => s.description.Contains(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't intersect a `string` with a `string[]` array, but you could split the `description` string into words and then do the intersection:

```
mediaList.RemoveAll(entry => entry.description.Split(new string[]{" "},
   StringSplitOptions.None).Intersect(criteria).Any());
```

This avoids the problem of matching words that are containing a substring of the criterion strings.