# Linq to Entities: Where In with 1 value and many columns

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities

I know that in sql you do something like this

```
WHERE 'val' IN (field1, field2, field3, field4, ...)
```

I was wondering if there is a way doing something similar using Linq to entities? The only thing I can think of right now is just to create a giant "or" statement of the fields I want to search over like the following

```
.where(m => 
    m.field1.Contains('val') ||
    m.field2.Contains('val') ||
    m.field3.Contains('val') ||
    m.field4.Contains('val'));
```

Is there a cleaner way of writing this search or is what I have as good as it gets?

Comment: See if this is a possible solution for you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667675/linq-where-list-contains-any-in-list

Comment: That post doesn't deal with multiple fields on the entity since "Genres" is just a single field on the entity.

Comment: This is not how [`IN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql) works. It does equality comparison, not `Contains`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
.Where(f => new string[] { f.field1, f.field2, f.field3 }.Any(s => s.Contains("val")));
```

which have the behavior of the code you posted, or

```
.Where(f => new string[] { f.field1, f.field2, f.field3 }.Contains("val"));
```

which check for equality.

But I can't say if it's a good idea regarding performance.

Here is an example of the code:

```
public class ClassWithFields
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 {get;set;}
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var listFields = new List<ClassWithFields>()
        {
                new ClassWithFields { Id = 1, Field1 = "val", Field2 = "qewr", Field3 = "asdqw" },
                new ClassWithFields { Id = 2, Field1 = "asdf", Field2 = "asdd", Field3 = "asdqw" },
                new ClassWithFields { Id = 3, Field1 = "asdf", Field2 = "qewr", Field3 = "qwvaleqwe" }
        };

        var containsVal = listFields.Where(f => new string[] { f.Field1, f.Field2, f.Field3 }.Any(s => s.Contains("val")));
        var equalsVal = listFields.Where(f => new string[] { f.Field1, f.Field2, f.Field3 }.Contains("val"));
    }
}
```

You can run it at https://dotnetfiddle.net/lXSoB4

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Contains() properly as pointed out by [Theodor Zoulias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264406/linq-to-entities-where-in-with-1-value-and-many-columns/56265194#comment99146636_56264406), because IN on SQL checks equality, while contains would be LIKE on SQL. also you are enclosing your string val with **'** instead of **"**, **'** only works for a single character.

Assuming you are trying to retrive "m" where any property has a certain value, you're going to have to use *reflection*:

First create a method to loop trough an object and match the desired value

```
public bool FieldSearch(object a, string b)
{
  //Get the type of your object, to loop through its properties
  Type t = a.GetType();
  //loop and check (the loop stops once the first property that matches has been found!)
  foreach(PropertyInfo p in t.GetProperties())
  {
    if(p.GetValue(a).ToString()==b)
    {
    return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Be careful with *GetProperties()*, you might want to add BidingAttributes because it retrieves **every**(public) property.

Now just use your new bool method on your linq: (not a good idea regarding performance depending on the context)

```
.where(m => FieldSearch(m,"val"))
```

Although all of this is possible, you probably have an *architecture problem*, because you are going to lose reference very quick, since this linq query returns any object that has that value on any field; without specifying which field.

There are probably better ways to do what you are trying to do..