# c# linq if item is in list and get matching items from list

Tags: c#, list, linq, contains

If my list contains: english cat, french cat, japanese dog, spanish dog

and I have an item: dog

Not only do I want to see if the list contains my item, but return the items that match, so I would expect: japanese dog, spanish dog

I have got as far as seeing if the item is in the list using the following code:

```
if (myList.Any(myItem.ToLower().Contains)) { }
```

Comment: try this:  var movies = _db.Movies.Where(p => p.Genres.Intersect(listOfGenres).Any());
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667675/linq-where-list-contains-any-in-list

Comment: If it's a list of strings, then I think `List<string> results = myList.Where(item => item.ToLower.Contains("dog");` would do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for something like this, using the `where` clause:

```
string filter = "dog";
IEnumerable<string> filteredItems = myList.Where(m => m.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var myList = new List<string>() { " japanese dog", "spanish dog", "english cat", "french cat" };
var dog = "Dog";

if (myList.Any(t=>t.Contains(dog.ToLower()))) {
    var result = myList.Where(t => t.Contains(dog.ToLower())).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use regex and to do that such as for dogs:

```
var animals = new List<string>() 
               { "japanese dog", "spanish dog", "english cat", "french cat" };

var dogs = animals.Where(type => Regex.IsMatch(type, "dog", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                  .ToList();

// Returns {"japanese dog",  "spanish dog" }
```

---

Why Regex you may ask, because its flexible and powerful...let me show:

Let us do some more advance linq work by having them sorted using the `ToLookup` extension and regex such as

```
var sortedbyDogs 
            = animals.ToLookup(type => Regex.IsMatch(type, "dog", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

which is grouped in memory like this:

[image: To lookup grouping result]

Then just extract cats such as

```
var cats = sortedbyDogs[false].ToList()
```

[image: List string of cats]

then pass in `true` for dogs.

---

But why split it by a boolean, what if there are more animals? Lets add a lemur to the list such as `… "french cat", "Columbian Lemur" };` we do this:

```
var sorted = animals.ToLookup(type => Regex.Match(type, 
                                                  "(dog|cat|lemur)", 
                                                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value);
```

[image]

Then to get our cats, here is the code:

`sorted["cat"].ToList()`